# Extending IPrincipal.IsInRole()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, authorization

In my case, I needed to give roles to users, but to specific departments, and I did not want to implement a new authorization mechanism which will require me to access the db everytime I want to check if the user is authorized for a specific role to a specific department.

So I thought I will just create an extension method `IsInRole` with two parameters `(role, departmentId)`. Here's the exact code:

```
public static bool IsInRole(this IPrincipal principal, string role, int departmentId)
{
    var ident = principal?.Identity;
    if (ident == null)
        return false;

    if (departmentId <= 0)
        return false;

    var roleDeparments = ((ClaimsIdentity)ident).FindFirst($"{role} departments")?.Value;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roleDeparments))
        return false;

    var inInRole = roleDeparments
        .Split(',')
        .Any(d => d == departmentId.ToString() || d == "all");

    return inInRole;
}
```

The user roles are saved in the db and are fetched once upon logging in, if the `departmentId` is set to NULL then it means this role is general to all departments. The Identity object is created at login time using the following method:

```
private ClaimsIdentity CreateIdentity(User user)
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(MyAuthentication.ApplicationCookie, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "Active Directory"));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.Name));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("DepartmentId", user.DepartmentId.ToString()));

    var roles = user.UserRoles
        .GroupBy(r => r.Role);

    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        var departments = role
            .Select(r => r.DepartmentId)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();

        bool isAll = departments.Any(d => d == null);

        string departmentIds = isAll
            ? "all"
            : string.Join(",", departments);

        identity.AddClaim(new Claim($"{role.Key.Name} departments", departmentIds));
    }

    return identity;
}
```

Now, I can simply do something like:

```
if (User.IsInRole("schedule viewer", 2))
{
   .....
}
```

Is this the right approach?

Comment: _"Is this the right approach?"_ Does it work? Then there's a good chance it's _one_ correct approach.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not familiar with the culture of this SE site, do not know how do people ask here in code review, not sure why is the downvote, i read the rules and it says that I should post working code, which I did. However any suggestions on what is an acceptable closing question of the post should be? I think new users should be "taught" on the specific culture of the site, not downvoted with a smart comment :) just saying. thanks anyway

Comment: _"not familiar with the culture of this SE site"_ Well did you consider to read the [tour] or attending the [help/on-topic] pages? Your code has to work as intended for all of your test cases, otherwise it doesn't _work_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I actually did. Yes is my answer to all the "test" questions, and I tried my best to stick to the recommendations. If you think my question has something wrong say it directly please, or feel free to click the [Edit] question which was intended to be used by users to improve things. No use to keep commenting while you are not tryin to answer either the question itself, or my question on what did I do wrong in my question :)

Comment: _"I actually did."_  Where is your [informed] badge then?

Comment: I read the on-topic page, I did not read the tour page since this is not my first SE site. I know how to use the site, all i need is the on-topic page of the specific site to get the "general culture" of that SE site.

Comment: I see that there is a close vote, which I'm not totally on board with, but I agree that a slightly more concrete example of how/why you'd use this would be useful.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8647/9357).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### IsInRole()

I don't like how the method parameters are validated. IMO the null-propagation operator shouldn't be used for everything because it reduces the readability. Having a null-propagation operator for "safely" "accessing" a property is OK if the object is the first on the right hand of an assignment like in checking for `var ident = principal?.Identity;` but nevertheless I personally would stick to a combined null check like so

```
if (principal == null || principal.Identity == null) { return false; }
```

But why areyou checking this at the beginning of the method ? I would check simple types first like `departmentId <= 0`.

The null-propagation operator here

```
var roleDeparments = ((ClaimsIdentity)ident).FindFirst($"{role} departments")?.Value;
```

could be missed at first glance making a maintainer of the code wonder what this is about, at least if he/she has not that good eyes like me. He/she can't grasp at first glance that you "safely" access the `Value` property here.

Can you spot the error here ?

```
var inInRole = roleDeparments
    .Split(',')
    .Any(d => d == departmentId.ToString() || d == "all");
```

Aside from spelling error in `inInRole` you could store the result of `departmentId.ToString()` in a variable to check in the `Any()`, but maybe the compiler is smart enough to do this for you.

Omitting braces `{}` for single line `if` statemenst is your responsibility. I wouldn't do it. If I would do it then only like `if (departmentId <= 0) return false;`

Using abbreviations leads to less readable code. Why don't you rename `ident`  to `identity` ?

Implementing the mentioned points leads to

```
public static bool IsInRole(this IPrincipal principal, string role, int departmentId)
{
    if (departmentId <= 0) { return false; }
    if (principal == null || principal.Identity == null) { return false; }  
    
    var identity = principal.Identity;

    var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst($"{role} departments");
    if (claim == null) { return false; }
    
    var roleDeparments = claim.Value;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roleDeparments)) { return false; }

    var isInRole = roleDeparments
        .Split(',')
        .Any(d => d == departmentId.ToString() || d == "all");

    return isInRole;
}
```

---

### CreateIdentity()

This made me wonder

```
bool isAll = departments.Any(d => d == null);
```

reading `isAll` and `Any`. After rereading your question I stumbled over

> if the departmentId is set to NULL then it means this role is general to all departments

This is screaming for a comment because a maintainer of the code should know this as well. Together with a better name it would be clear for a maintainer what is happening here like so

```
// If one of the user.UserRoles has a DepartmentId which is null,
// the role is general for all departments
bool isGeneralForAllDepartments = departments.Any(d => d == null);  

string departmentIds = isGeneralForAllDepartments 
    ? "all"
    : string.Join(",", departments);
```